# A script that can tell how many lines per second

Tags: perl, bash, unix

I don't know how else to explain this, but im trying to tell how many lines are added to a list per second. i cant figure it out, looking for a solution in Perl.

Even if its in bash it works.

Comment: Is this "list" a file?

Comment: Indeed it is zaid, just a random file that has lines added per second and i want to calculate it.

Comment: How big the file gets? Does it change name or is truncated at some point?

Comment: It does not change name, and the file is at 61k lines at the moment, but it will go up to 4-40million soon.

Comment: You haven't tried at all to explain your problem. *"How many lines are added to a list per second"* can mean many things, and `Zaid` has found that your list is really a file (acccording to you it is *"just a random file"*). If *"in bash it works"* then please show your working bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line-counter.pl

```
#!/bin/perl

my $last_time = time();
my $line_count = 0;
while (<>){
   if ( time() > $last_time ){
     $last_time = time();
     print $line_count . "\n";
     $line_count = 0;
   }
   $line_count++;
}
```

Usage: tail -f /the/file.log | perl -w line-counter.pl

Comment: This relies on the fact that the loop executes at least once per second, which may not be true on a heavily loaded machine. To be correct, you need to divide the current line count by the *difference* between `time()` and `$last_time`.

Comment: Does anyone think they can help find a solution without having to tail the file.